# Not able to add 'View Customer User' button to the custom page layout in the Salesforce lightning

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

We are trying to add **View custom user** button in to the **Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions** section of the newly created page layout in the person account object

This button is not visible in the list of buttons as shown below

[image: Salesforce page layout editor]

This behavior is same across all the sandboxes and production. Except in one of the dev sandbox where we can see the button and drop it to the page layout.

[image]

Are we missing any settings here?

We verified the permission required for this button to be visible at the profile level, which is Manage external User.

This permission is given in all the sandboxes where the button is not currently visible to add to the page layout.

Comment: Stupid question but do you have customer or partner community (sorry, the name changed to "experience") now? And at least 1 license in the org? Maybe community was only enabled in that 1 sandbox or some license trial you had expired. What happens when you use sfdx/vscode or even changesets to migrate the layout from "good" sandbox to another, what error if any is thrown?